# Big Data: Which NoSQL suits for the below data

Tags: database, bigdata, nosql

My sample data looks like below and it contains millions of customers and for each customer there is a friends list with friend name, id and favorite sports. Here which NoSQL database suits for storing this kind of data for easy access and frequent update for each customer friends list values.
Cust1, {(aaa,001,cricket),
        (bbb,002,tennis),
        ...............
        ...............
       }
Cust2,{(iii,011,chess),
        (jjj,022,cricket),
        ...............
        ...............
       }
Cust3,{....
       ....
       }

Thanks,
Arjun

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are 4 types of NoSql:

1. Key/Map
2. Document Database
3. Column Family
4. Graph

Clearly your data fits on type 2 Document Databases: there are two common databases

1. https  ://www.mongodb.org/
2. http  ://couchdb.apache.org/

Now the difficult part is to decided which one, because they were developed with different objectives in mind according to the CAP theorem https:   //en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem, but here you a have a very informative post http:  //blog.scottlogic.com/2014/08/04/mongodb-vs-couchdb.html